# How to get all labels in a column out of one hot encoded columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, dataset

Reversing One Hot Encoding of Multi-labeled Data.
I want to convert 20+ one hot encoded columns into a column with label names.
The data is also multi-labeled, and in the label column, I expect to mention all the labels.

From this:

```
LabelA  labelB labelC 
  0        0     1
  1        1     0
```

To:

```
LabelA  labelB labelC   labels
      0        0     1   ['labelC']
      1        1     0   ['labelA','labelB']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will convert all the One Hot Encoded column labels into a single column with a list of labels in it.

From this:

```
LabelA  labelB labelC 
  0        0     1
  1        1     0
```

To:

```
LabelA  labelB labelC   labels
      0        0     1   ['labelC']
      1        1     0   ['labelA','labelB']
```

Code:

```
def get_col_name(row):    
    b = (df.loc[row.name] == 1)
    c = list(b.index[b])
    return c

df['label'] = df.apply(get_col_name, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with df.idxmax(axis=1). This returns the value of the column that contains the maximum value among the columns in df. In the case of one hot encoded columns, it would return the label.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'values':['val5','val2','val3']})
ohe_df = pd.get_dummies(df['values'])

# Select the One Hot Encoding Values
ohe_cols = ['val5','val2','val3']
result = ohe_df[ohe_cols].idxmax(axis=1)
result
```

Comment: It works well for single labeled ones, I am working with Multi-labels.

Comment: What do you mean with "Multi-labels"?

Comment: If you generated onehot columns from more than one column, you should specify which ones are the values that correspond to each original column (like the `ohe_cols` I defined). Those values should be stored in your OneHotEncoder objects.